# Optimization and accelerating the loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you optimize this three snippets of code?
Especially the third because there are many combinations between the list values and the time is dangerously longer with 1000 inputs.

Code 1:

```
e00=[]
for i in range(len(c1)):
    for j in range(len(d1[i])):
        if d1[i][j]%2==0:
           d = [c1[i],d1[i][j]]
           e00.append(d)
```

Code 2:

```
sciezki=[]
for i in range(len(out2)):     
    x1 = out2[i][-len(out2[i])]
    x2 =out2[i][-1]    
    z1 = nx.shortest_path(g, x1, x2)  
    if z1 == out2[i] and len(z1)==8:
          sciezki.append(z1)
```

Code 3:

```
out=[] 
for h in range(len(k)):
    if len(out)!=0:
       k2 = [out, k[h]]
       for q in range(len(k2[0])):
           for w in range(len(k2[1])):
               r = list(chain(k2[0][q],k2[1][w]))
               p = [n for n, _ in groupby(r)]
               if len(p)==h+2:
                  out.append(p)  
    else:
       for i in range(len(k[0])):
           for j in range(len(k[1])):
               r = list(chain(k[0][i],k[1][j]))
               p = [n for n, _ in groupby(r)]
               if len(p)==3:
                   out.append(p)
```

Comment: Usually it is better to iterate over the list directly, so `for ci in c`, instead of `for i in range(len(c)):`

Comment: Start with analyzing the algorithm and see if you can make it faster. After that you turn to code details.

Comment: @klutt this is always the worst, the man sits a few days over the algorithm, and then you have to think about the possible algorithm change :))

Comment: Could you describe what your goal is?

Comment: If you're working with large lists of lists, you definitely should take a look at [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/).

Comment: @Eric Duminil The goal is very simple - acceleration. It's generally about choosing the fastest paths in the tree graph under certain conditions, and my system starts to sweat at just 1000 nodes: /

Comment: I meant: What's the goal of the algorithm?

Comment: https://dpaste.de/bJ11 Only code 3 here before small changes.

Comment: Well, without addressing the underlying algorithm I doubt you'll gain much in performance. But there are certain obvious things, like trying to iterate directly over a list rather than using indexing, and oh, don't do `r = list(chain(...))` just use `r = chain(...)`. And another micro-optimization of course is to "in-line" the `.append` method call: `out = []; append_out = out.append` then use `append_out(p)` in place of `out.append(p)`. But all of these will be very minor, your problem is algorithmic complexity.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Well, I thought I would avoid this for now;) thanks for the tips, i will use :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code 1**

Use a conditional list comprehension together with enumeration:

```
e00 = [[c_val, d_val] 
       for i, c_val in enumerate(c1) 
       for d_val d1[i] 
       if not d_val % 2]
```

**Code 2**

Only slight modifications required.

```
g = ...  # Undefined in sample code.
sciezki = []
for out2_val in out2:     
    x1 = out2_val[-len(out2_val)]
    x2 = out2_val[-1]    
    z1 = nx.shortest_path(g, x1, x2)  
    if z1 == out2_val and len(z1) == 8:
        sciezki.append(z1)
        x = '\n'.join(map(str,sciezki))  # Remove if possible.
```

Comment: Właściwie to 'x' tutaj jest niepotrzebne, mój punkt widzenia. 'g' to `g = nx.Graph ()` z Networkx. 2 kod polega na porównaniu pierwszego i ostatniego węzła i przejścia przez "shortest_path", czy dany wybór jest jednoznaczny.